# Detect presence of inverse pairs in two columns of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, graph, networkx

I have a dataframe with two columns; `source`, and `target`. I would like to detect inverse rows, i.e. for a pair of values `(source, target)`, if there exists a pair of values `(target, source)` then assign `True` to a new column.

My attempt:

```
cols = ['source', 'target']
_cols = ['target', 'source']
sub_edges = edges[cols]
sub_edges['oneway'] = sub_edges.apply(lambda x: True if x[x.isin(x[_cols])] else False, axis=1)
```

Comment: Please include a small subset of your sub_edges DataFrame as a __copyable__ piece of code that can be used for testing as well as your expected or desired output. See  [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a lambda function using similar logic to that in your example. We check if there are any rows in the dataframe with a reversed source/target pair.

Incidentally, the column name 'oneway' indicates to me the opposite of the logic described in your question, but to change this we can just remove the `not` in the lambda function.

### Code

```
import pandas as pd
import random

edges = {"source": random.sample(range(20), 20),
         "target": random.sample(range(20), 20)}

df = pd.DataFrame(edges)

df["oneway"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: not df[
        (df["source"] == x["target"]) & (df["target"] == x["source"]) & (df.index != x.name)
    ].empty,
    axis=1,
)
```

### Output

```
    source  target  oneway
0        9      11   False
1       16       1    True
2        1      16    True
3       11      14   False
4        4      13   False
5       18      15   False
6       14      17   False
7       13      12   False
8       19      19   False
9       12       3   False
10      10       6   False
11      15       5   False
12       3      18   False
13      17       0   False
14       6       7   False
15       5      10   False
16       7       2   False
17       8       9   False
18       0       4   False
19       2       8   False
```

Comment: Lots of thanks. That what I was looking for

Comment: I noticed an error the row number 8 shouldn't be true but false. I found that I got more True value than expected. How can I correct it?

Comment: @aba2s row 8 is True because there is an edge from node 19 to itself. Is that not expected behaviour?

Comment: It is not what expected. Here I only want if given tuple (u,v) and if there exist a tuple (v,u) then give it true else false. So line number 8 doesn't have another inverse line. legend : u=origin and v = target

Comment: @aba2s But if (19, 19) exists then surely (19, 19) also exists :P. Either way, I've altered the function to return False for these cases.

Answer (score 1):

Another, slightly faster method, using pandas pivot and melt.

```
d = df.pivot(
    index='source', 
    columns='target'
).fillna(0)

index = d.index.union(d.columns)
d = d.reindex(index=index, columns=index, fill_value=0)


e = (
    (d + d.T)
    .rename_axis('source', axis=0)
    .rename_axis('target', axis=1)
).reset_index().melt('source')

e[e.value == 2].sort_values(by=['source', 'target'])
```

This will show you the first order loops in your edgelist.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a need to do this today and just thought I'd throw another mechanism out there for fun: merge on reverse order columns.  Here's an example that adds the index of the reverse edge.

```py
import pandas as pd

def find_reverse_edges(df_in, cols):
    rcols = list(reversed(cols))
    df = df_in[cols].reset_index()
    df = df.merge(df, how="left", left_on=cols, right_on=rcols, suffixes=["", "_r"])
    return df[cols + ["index_r"]]

# Test it:
df = pd.DataFrame({"source": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "C"],
                   "target": ["B", "C", "D", "C", "A"]})

df_rev = find_reverse_edges(df, ["source", "target"])

df_rev[~df_rev.index_r.isna()]
```

Result:

```py
  source target  index_r
1      A      C      4.0
4      C      A      1.0
```